# Setting the target of an action to an NSObject

Tags: ios, class, action, target, nsobject

I want to set the target of an action to the class that it is created in. However when I attempt this the `app crashes`.

Test.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class Test;
@protocol TestDelegate<NSObject>
@end

@interface Test : NSObject
{
    UIView *theView;
}
@property (assign) id<TestDelegate> delegate;
- (id)initWithView:(UIView *)view;
@end
```

Test.m:

```
#import "Test.h"

@implementation Test

- (id)initWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    if (self=[super init]) {
        theView = view;
        int size = 60;

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(buttonAction:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [button setTitle:@"button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.size.width/2 - size, view.frame.size.height/2 - size, size, size);
        [view addSubview:button];    
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
     theView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
@end
```

The **error**:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0x0)

argv    char ** 0x27db7d04  0x27db7d04

*argv   char *  "/var/mobile/Applications/EC1DE795-A5B7-4E8F-AC3D-E42551D1B284/appName.app/appName" 0x27db7da8

**argv  char    '/' '/'

argc    int 1   1
```

Comment: I am thinking theView has release when you use it in your action method.

Comment: Thank you for the response, the error appears even if I comment out the line setting the background color

Comment: At what point does application crash? Have you tried execute the app step-by-step in the debugger?

Comment: it crashes as soon as the button is pressed. I know that it is crashing because the button is trying to call a method that isn't where it there. so I need to set the target correctly, however I don't know how to do so

Comment: In the target-action pattern that UIButton implements target is not retained. This is to avoid retain cycles, because target is usually a view controller and the view controller directly or indirectly holds strong reference to the views and controls it manages. You need to guarantee that the Test object is not released when the button sends its action. Some other object, probably the one that created the Test object must hold strong reference to the Test object for as long as the object is target of the button.